# O que é lógica difusa?

Tags: terminologia, lógica, inteligência-artificial, lógica-difusa

Estudando sobre inteligência artificial observei muito o termo lógica difusa, ou *fuzzy logic*. O que é essa tal de lógica difusa e quais são suas aplicações? Sei que é diferente da lógica booleana, mas o que difere as duas lógicas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Lógica Fuzzy é uma lógica que difere da booleana pelo fato de trabalhar com uma escala de valores e não apenas com a escala binária `true` e `false`. Essa escala de valores determina o grau de pertinência de um elemento em determinado conjunto. Dessa forma, é possível ser menos radical na classificação de dados, pois ao invés de dizer simplesmente que um elemento pertence ou não a um conjunto você pode dizer que ele pertence com um certo grau de pertinência. Dá uma olhada nesse [artigo](http://aquilesburlamaqui.wdfiles.com/local--files/logica-aplicada-a-computacao/texto_fuzzy.pdf) que eu escrevi para maiores informações.

Comment: +1 Que legal achar uma programadora e estudiosa da computação aqui no SOPT. Mas o upvote foi pelo conteúdo, de verdade =P Entretanto, se você puder complementar com um exemplo resumido, ilustrações, ou código, acho que ficaria mais completo. (poderia usar algo dessa questão [FuzzyLogic in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886032/fuzzylogic-in-javascript) para criar um snippet)... são só ideias, claro.

Comment: Realmente a sugestão do @MiguelAngelo agregaria muito na questão em termos de conhecimento. Entretanto, sua resposta foi direto ao ponto e respondeu a questão :-)

Comment: Eu preferi ser mais direta pois respostas extensas as vezes deixam de ser lidas. Mas deixei o plus do artigo caso a pessoa tenha interesse em se aprofundar :)