# Os operadores ==, ===, != e !== podem ser considerador de "lógica difusa"?

Tags: operadores, lógica-difusa

A dúvida é simples e apenas por curiosidade, num ponto de vista matemático, nós temos algo como comparadores por proporção (ou de [**Lógica difusa**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_difusa)):

**Exemplo:**

Representação descrita:

```
x pode ser de 1 até 100 igual a y
```

Representando com PHP:

```
if($x >= 1 and $x <= 100){
    echo 'x é ' . $x . '/100 igual a y';
}
```

Em PHP, temos os operadores de comparação:

- `==`
- `===`
- `!=`
- `!==`

Sabendo o conceito matemático dito anteriormente, o interpretador do PHP usa esse conceito pra entender esses operadores?

OBS: A dúvida **não é** sobre a diferença entre eles, e sim, se levando em conta a lógica matemática apenas se podemos considerar como operadores de **logica difusa**, ou seja, de igualdade baseada em proporção.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não é sobre isso, e sim qual a lógica que as linguagens usam pra identificar o que esses operadores fazem.

Comment: Sua duvida me pareceu meio ampla pelo seu comentário de agora.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta de novo, pra ver se deixo mais claro, mas pode ser que minha duvida não faça sentido mesmo

Comment: Não, não podem. Lógica difusa não retorna "sim" ou "não". A lógica difusa é o rompimento do axioma do terceiro excluído do sistema axiomático da lógica booleana. Esses operadores não retornam "39% de igualdade".

Comment: Leitura recomendado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152106/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ah entendi agora, eu também fiz confusão. Obrigado! - Retirei o voto de fechamento

Comment: O @JeffersonQuesado respondeu certinho o que eu queria saber

Comment: @AnthraxisBR perfeito, deixei um +1 agora que a pergunta ficou um pouco mais clara, se me permite tenho uma sugestão de edição, qualquer coisa basta fazer o rollback se discordar

Comment: @AnthraxisBR, já que a pergunta foi fechada, acabei colando a minha resposta num snippet: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1702821

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado perfeito!

Comment: Meu posicionamento a respeito do porquê essa pergunta deve ser reaberta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6857/64969

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Não é um operador de lógica difusa propriamente dito. Não fortemente. Mas pode ser considerado um operador booleano, então *de certo modo* seria também difuso. Então, para a pergunta "é um operador de lógica difusa?", eu respondo 11.39%.

Para começar, precisamos definir o que é um *operador de tipo* para, então, definir o que é um *operador de lógica difusa*.

A descrição do que um `BinaryOperator` do Java 8 é que um operador binário uma função binária em que os operandos e a saída são do mesmo tipo. [Leia a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html). Por cima, é como se fosse isso:

```java
public interface BinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T,T,T> {
}
```

Matematicamente, um operador n-ário é uma função que recebe n operandos do mesmo tipo e o retorno também é do mesmo tipo. No caso, para considerar `==`, `===`, `!=` e `!==` como operadores, eles só devem ser considerados a nível de operandos que também são da lógica difusa.

Mas, para esses aí em específico, independente de quais são os operandos, o retorno é apenas `SIM` ou `NÃO`. Sem terceiro termo.

Mas, o que é a lógica booleana? Formalmente, é composta de 3 axiomas:

- identidade
- não contradição
- terceiro excluído

Você pode ler mais sobre o assunto [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/274114/64969). E o que é a lógica difusa? É uma mudança nesses axiomas, mais especificamente a remoção do terceiro excluído. No caso, a lógica difusa permite que você tenha algo 11.3% verdade. A mudança é que existam 2 valores (já previstos no booleano) e que exista todo um intervalo contínuo entre esses valores.

No caso, a lógica booleana pode ser mapeada para a difusa da seguinte maneira:

- `SIM ==> 1`
- `NÃO ==> 0`

O mapeamento contrário não é possível. A cardinalidade do conjunto de valores booleano é finita, não tem como fazer uma bijeção para o contínuo que é o conjunto dos valores difuso. Você até pode fazer uma sobrejeção, mas não seria a função inversa. Se existisse uma função que transforma os valores booleanos em difusos chamada `bool2fuzzy` e a função que transforma da lógica difusa para a booleana chamada `fuzzy2bool`, as seguintes fórmulas estão corretas:

```
seja fuz uma variável pertencente a Difuso
se fuz não pertencer a {0, 1}:
    bool2fuzzy(fuzzy2bool(fuz)) != fuz
senão:
    bool2fuzzy(fuzzy2bool(fuz)) == fuz
```

### Operadores em linguagem de programação vs operadores em matemática

Bem, devo ter feita uma confusão na sua cabeça, ser? Sim ou não? 67%?

Na matemática, um operador (binário) é algo assim:

[image: função de Q,Q em Q]

Já em linguagens de programação, não usamos a noção *matemática pura* do que é um operador. Por exemplo, você pode fazer `"123" + 4` em PHP, Java e outras linguagens. No caso, as linguagens de programação usam *operadores sintáticos*. Um operador sintático não entra no reino da matemática, mas no reino da sintaxe. No caso, para operador sintático binário é quem preenche o espaço de `<op>` na produção gramatical abaixo:

[image: produção gramatical que representa uma operação binária]

Então, no caso das linguagens de programação, a estrutura determina se algo é chamado de operador ou não. Inclusive [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412969/64969) reforça isso.

### Conclusão

- operadores binários na matemática mapeiam 2 objetos em um terceiro objeto, contanto que todos esses 3 objetos pertençam ao "mesmo universo"
- linguagens de programação chamam de "operadores" algo que encaixa na estrutura de operação
- comparação, forte ou frouxa, igualdade ou diferença, são operadores de lógica booleana (matematicamente falando quando tratam como entrada valores booleanos)
- comparação, forte ou frouxa, igualdade ou diferença, são 11.39% operadores de lógica difusa
- esta resposta está 73% correta

Comment: +0.872, boa resposta

Comment: @bfavaretto, essa resposta é boa e é ruim até ela ser lido. Resposta de Schroedinger. Então essa resposta é 0.489506 ruim =D (considerando que a sobreposição de estados quânticos `bom^2 + ruim^2 = 1`).

Answer (score 5):

Não tem nada a ver uma coisa com outra. A presença de diferentes operadores de igualdade tem a ver com "tipagem fraca".

== e != testam igualdade, e se necessário convertem implicitamente o tipo de um dos valores comparados para viabilizar a comparação. Por exemplo, "2" == 2 é verdadeiro porque a string é convertida para número antes de efetuar a comparação. Mas não tem nada de difuso: "2" == 2.0000000001 continua sendo falso.

Algo semelhante acontece com outros operadores, por isso o PHP possui um operador específico de concatenação, pois "2" + "2" retorna 4, então "2" . "2" retorna "22".

Já === e !== testam **identidade**, que para tipos simples é a mesma coisa que igualdade sem conversão de tipo. "2" === 2 é falso, "2" === "2" é verdadeiro, 2 === 2 é verdadeiro.

Aproveitando o ensejo, alguns conceitos referentes a tipos:

Tipagem fraca: faz conversões implícitas. Exemplos: Javascript, PHP.

Tipagem forte: não faz conversões implícitas. Exemplos: Python, C, C++...

Tipagem dinâmica: uma variável pode trocar de tipo ao longo do escopo. Exemplos: Python, PHP, Javascript.

Tipagem estática: uma variável não pode trocar de tipo. Exemplos: C, C++.

Embora cada linguagem tenha um caráter, quase sempre há exceções. Por exemplo, Python, C e C++ usam tipagem forte, porém permitem o uso de variáveis de outros tipos em lugar de uma condição *booleana*, fazendo a conversão implícita. Também é comum a "promoção de tipo automática" quando e.g. um número inteiro é somado a um de ponto flutuante.

Linguagens ultra-modernas como Swift, Rust, Go usam tipagem muito forte, não fazem nem mesmo promoções de tipo, nem conversão automática ente tipos numéricos, pois a experiência mostra que essas conversões e promoções são fontes infinitas de bugs.

Comment: Não entendi os negativos