# Diferença entre "==" e "==="

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estava desenvolvendo um código `javascript` e vi que o compilador acusava erro na igualdade que eu fazia naquele momento, porem não dava erro nenhum na execução.

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença da igualdade "==" e "===" no `javascript`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Victor verifique esse post, tem umas informações que descrevem bem a diferença entra "==", "===" e Object.is https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Igualdade ---------------------------- "==" : igual a;
"===" : igual valor e o tipo; x === 5 true x === "5" false

Comment: Duplicada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280978/os-operadores-e-podem-ser-considerador-de-l%C3%B3gica-difusa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No javascript:
`==` não leva o tipo da variável em consideração, já o
`===` leva o tipo da variável em consideração

Veja alguns exemplos:

```
var verdadeiro = '1' == 1;
var falso = '1' === 1;


var var1 = 'true' == true;                 // false
var var2 = '0' == false;                   // true
var var3 = null == undefined;              // true
var var4 = false == null;                  // false
var var5 = null == 0;                      // false
var var6 = '' == 0;                        // true
var var7 = '\t\n' == 0;                    // true
var var8 = '1' == true;                    // true
```