# O que são considerados operadores nas linguagem de programação?

Tags: característica-linguagem, operadores, sintaxe, independente-de-linguagem, token

Queria saber se um *token* é considerado um operador quando realiza uma ação?

Comment: Após a [análise léxica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token) de um código, os operadores são um dos tipos de tokens que podem ser encontrados... Resta saber o que você quer dizer com "realiza uma ação", pois a execução do código vem bem depois dessa fase...

Comment: @fernandosavio O termo “realiza uma ação" foi usado para referenciar a uma mudança de “estado”. Exemplo: int x = 0;  o estado de x é "desconhecido", após o operador “realizar sua ação” o estado de x é 0, ou seja, o operador (=) mudou o estado "desconhecido" de x para 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, mas o contrário é verdadeiro. Tudo o que está escrito em um código acaba formando um *token*, inclusive *tokens* costumam ser formados por outros *tokens*, então um operador, assim como quaisquer outras construções da linguagem, são *tokens*.

*Token* é um termo dentro de uma taxonomia, então o mesmo objeto pode ter vários nomes de forma hierárquica, e chamá-lo de *token* é uma forma genérica e pode ser suficiente em certos contexto e ambígua em outros, exigindo uma melhor qualificação, então por exemplo você pode ter um contexto que precisá-la chamar esse mesmo objeto de operador, porque ele é isto.

O operador é um dos *tokens* possíveis e uma construção de linguagem que determina uma operação em valores.

[image: Hierarquia de tokens]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não encontrei nenhum problema nessa resposta, poderia justificar o negativo?

Comment: Na verdade são 2 perguntas distintas, o que são tokens e o que são operadores, talvez falte conceituar o 2°, no sentido do seu uso propriamente dito, as operações comuns a todas as linguagens. Certamente já vi algo por aqui. Posso estar errado.