# Qual é a diferença entre a lógica de fuzzy e a lógica booleana?

Tags: lógica, lógica-difusa

Estava [lendo](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/10/22618) a respeito da lógica de fuzzy e percebi que ela tem relações com a lógica booleana. Entretanto, fiquei bem confuso no ponto que define a relação da lógica de fuzzy com a booleana, alem do mais, outras dúvidas me surgiram também.

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é a diferença entre a lógica de fuzzy e a lógica booleana e o que define a relação entre ambas?
2. Podemos utilizar a logica de fuzzy na programação ou ela é restrita
   apenas para outros campos da matemática?

Comment: Eu já respondi isso (ou pincelei) em alguma resposta. Basicamente é a lógica booleana tradicional com a mudança do axioma do terceiro excluído

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado "mudança do axioma do terceiro excluído" ? Fiquei mais confuso agora kkkk

Comment: Aqui eu falo dos 3 axiomas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/274114/64969; axioma da identidade, axioma da não contradição e axioma do terceiro excluído. Mas não falo de fuzzy/difusa em duas das 3 resposta que menciono _axioma_...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é lógica difusa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152106/o-que-%c3%a9-l%c3%b3gica-difusa); me avise se não for duplicata

Comment: Que tal [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281559/64969)? Eu explico minimamente o que é a mudança no axioma do terceiro excluído

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado a relação é a escala de valores entre `1` e `0` que na logica difusa ficaria `0.001` e `0.11` ou `1`, seria isto? Ou seria um valor que represente `1` e `0`, como um terceiro valor?

Comment: Lógica difusa não é quântica, não representa ao mesmo tempo 0 e 1. O axioma da lógica booleana "terceiro excluído" fala o seguinte: há dois valores, e apenas dois, qualquer terceiro valor é idêntico a um dos dois valores anteriores, ou não pertence à lógica booleana. Portanto, o "terceiro valor" foi "excluído" da lógica booleana. Daí, axioma do terceiro excluído. Todo o resto da lógica booleana só é válido por conta desse axioma.

Answer (score 1):

A ***lógica de fuzzy*** é a forma de lógica multivalorada, na qual os valores de verdade das variáveis podem ser qualquer número real **entre** 0 (falso) e 1 (verdadeiro). Já a ***lógica booleana*** as variáveis e funções podem ter apenas valores 0 e 1, nessa lógica temos também as portas lógicas: **and**: você tem que ter todos os valores para a sentença ser verdadeira. **or**: é necessário apenas um dos valores para a sentença ser verdadeira. **xor**: retorna verdadeiro apenas quando os valores de entrada forem diferentes, caso contrário, falso.

Answer (score 0):

Só para complementar a resposta da @maria-gabi , a **logica fuzzy** pode suportar valores que não sejam necessariamente verdadeiro ou falso.

Por exemplo para alguma condição ou método.

- Verdadeiro = 1
- Parcialmente Verdadeiro = 0.75
- Indiferente = 0.50
- Parcialmente Falso = 0.25
- Falso = 0

Você pode determinar quantos valores quiser para cada alternativa desde que seja um valor dentro do range de 0 à 1;

---

Já em logica booleana os valores devem ser explicitamente verdadeiro ou falso para alguma condição.

Vou ao cinema se **tenho dinheiro** e (**and**) se o cinema está **aberto**.
ou seja se as duas variáveis forem verdadeira a condição ir ao cinema sera executada.

você pode trocar os operadores lógicos como por exemplo no lugar de **and** (e) colocar um **or** (ou);